# How does the conversion of int value to unsigned char in memset() work?

Tags: c++, c

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

`memset()` sets the first num bytes of ptr to value. I want to use `memset()` to set all bytes of a void buffer to:

```
00000000
11111111
10101010
01010101
```

For "00000000" I can use

```
memset(buffer, '0', BUF_LENGTH);
```

But am I right to assume

```
memset(buffer, '1', BUF_LENGTH);
```

won't end in "11111111", but in "00000001"? I've read that '-1' would do the trick, but why? And what value would i need to set bitwise 10101010 or 01010101?

Comment: From the manpage, 1 will be converted to byte-size. So sending in int(1) should set every byte to 0x01.To set e.g. 01010101, send in 0x55 (unsigned).

Comment: What is definition of `buffer`? If it's `char buffer[SIZE];` or similar,  then `sizeof(&buffer)` is definitely wrong, because it returns size of a pointer.

Comment: @user694733 Sorry I left that part out. It's `void* buffer`

Comment: If it's `void` pointer, then `sizeof` will definitely not give you the correct size.

Comment: The value -1 (without quotes)  is 11111111b in 2's complement representation.

Comment: @user694733 Since I know the correct size of the buffer I edited the question to represent this through `BUF_LENGTH` . (OT: Just to complete this, thought I already commented on your comment. Thank you all!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

memset operates on a byte-by-byte basis.

To zero the memory use:

```
memset(buffer, 0, BUF_LENGTH);
```

To set each byte to the value 1 use:

```
memset(buffer, 0x01, BUF_LENGTH);
```

For the binary pattern 10101010 use:

```
memset(buffer, 0xAA, BUF_LENGTH);
```

For the binary pattern 01010101 use:

```
memset(buffer, 0x55, BUF_LENGTH);
```

To set all bits in the buffer to 1 use:

```
memset(buffer, 0xFF, BUF_LENGTH);
```

BUF_LENGTH would be the length used in the array definition, e.g.

```
#define BUF_LENGTH 256
char buffer[BUF_LENGTH];
```

or what you used as length in dynamic memory allocation:

```
#define BUF_LENGTH 256
char *buffer = malloc(BUF_LENGTH);
```

Do not quote the 0 as in your code example, as this represents the ascii character '0', which has the value 0x30 (see http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: For `1010 1010` use memset(buffer, 0xAA, BUF_LENGTH);
and for `01010101` use memset(buffer, 0x55, BUF_LENGTH);

Comment: Can you add this to the answer

Answer (score 1):

If this is C++, use binary literals, for instance `0b10101010` and `0b01010101`.

If it is C, translate to hexadecimal, `0xAA` and `0x55`.

(Using `'0'` and `'1'` will most likely result in 00110000 and 00110001, respectively.)

Comment: Binary literals are not a part of C standard.

Comment: @user694733 Was browsing [c++] and missed the C tag. Clarified.